# Save file into another computer - Python

Tags: python, file, flask

Currently I know that if your want to know the ip of the user login to your website 
just do  this code

```
home1 = request.remote_addr
```

so I already get their ip.

next I would like to save the file into their desktop when they trying to download a file.
So I did this

```
    home = os.path.join(home1,expanduser("~"))
    home2 = os.path.join(home,"try.txt")
    ap = csv.writer(file(home2,'wb'))
    ap.writerows(["HELLOW WORLD"])
    db.session.commit()
```

but it seems that it save to the server pc not on the user's pc who is accessing the site. Sorry I'm still new about it.
Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not write to the directory.

Instead you make to should return a response. if you are using flask (im guessing you are), you can use the send_file api.

```
from flask import send_file

@app.route("/<file_name>")
def getFile(file_name):
    return send_file(file_name, as_attachment=True)
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file

Comment: Hi I tried your code but it gives me this error. TypeError: getFile() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given). Is there something I'm missing?. Sorry I'm quite new on this. Thanks

Comment: Hi, check out Variable Rules in the flask quickstart : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/ documentation. You function getFile, will get its parameters from the @app.route('/<file_name>') if you no not want to pass that parameter just do def getFile(): your logic here return send_file. This if you post this as another question, i might show it to you better than just commenting